# Filter Age on 2 different Buckets

Tags: salesforce-lightning

*Not sure if this is the correct thread*

I have a simple report group by Chat and Non Chat. And I only need to show cases on ¨Chat¨ >= 48 hours (Age) and >= 180  hours for Non Chat..

Any help is needed, thanks.

My report looks like this and I need to list down the cases highlighted in red as shown on the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us4Qk.png)

Tried to check the filter fields to no avail.